# Does await Promise.all in JavaScript Run Tasks in Parallel Like await Task.WhenAll in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a CPU-intensive task running on a list of items from my Colleague. His Code (Typescript/javascript)

```
await Promise.all(items.data?.map(item => processItem(item)));
```

I've also implemented the same process in C#, where it runs significantly faster (around 400ms) using:

```
await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(item => ProcessItem(item)));
```

Is the JavaScript code running tasks in parallel, similar to how C#'s await Task.WhenAll works, or does it process items one after another?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. Nothing runs parallel without workers or new processes.

Comment: Side note: `WhenAll` *does not* run anything in parallel in C# either... the explanation in Node.js duplicate equally applies to C# code.